# How to update name attribute in python enum?

Tags: python, enums

When doing a basic `Enum` in python:

```py
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

Color.RED.name  # "RED"
```

the `name` attribute lets get a string representation of the item which is exactly the strigified name of the attribute: RED => "RED"

Is there a way to update this rule with, for instance, a dict or a factory, so as to have for example:

```py
Color.RED.name  # "my color is RED"
```

Answer (score 2):

After digging a bit in the source code of `Enum`, I have seen that the `name` attribute is indeed a `@DynamicClassAttribute` so that doing:

```py
from types import DynamicClassAttribute
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

    @DynamicClassAttribute
    def name(self):
        name = super(Color, self).name
        return f"my name is {name}"

Color.RED.name  # "my name is RED"
```

will do the trick